# how to get access to endpoint with API Key through Python requests?

Tags: python, api, rest

I'm trying to get access to an endpoint with an API Key but I keep getting 401 error code.

I'm trying to collect the content through python requests library.

For example:

```
API Specification

Get list of people

Method GET
Endpoint https://api.json-generator.com/templates/-xdNcNKYtTFG/data
API Key: vza4lbzrzy3cyhg4nbzyjhmqzjlqr2p3qibd9986 (Don't worry. It is a public key.)

Example: Fetch From API by command line

curl --request GET -H "Authorization: Bearer R4iN..." --url https://api.json-generator.com/templates/tAu-9/data
```

Can anyone help? This a code I wrote in python:

```
import requests

url ='https://api.json-generator.com/templates/-xdNcNKYtTFG/data'

api_key='vza4lbzrzy3cyhg4nbzyjhmqzjlqr2p3qibd9986'

headers = {'Authorization' : api_key}

r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
```

Comment: Your `curl` command and code do not match.  Note: the text `Bearer ` in the header _value_.

Comment: different APIs need different mentods - some need it in `URL`, other in `POST data`, and other in `header`. You would have to show URL for documentation.

Comment: I added back `curl` example because it explains everything.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `'Bearer '` to API key - like in `curl` example.

```
headers = {'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + api_key}
```

---

```
import requests

url ='https://api.json-generator.com/templates/-xdNcNKYtTFG/data'

api_key = 'vza4lbzrzy3cyhg4nbzyjhmqzjlqr2p3qibd9986'

headers = {'Authorization' : f'Bearer {api_key}'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

data = r.json()

for item in data:
    print(item['name'])
```

Result:

```
{'last': 'Pace', 'first': 'Irma'}
{'last': 'Terry', 'first': 'Jaime'}
{'last': 'Wise', 'first': 'Solomon'}
{'last': 'Gutierrez', 'first': 'Alyson'}
{'last': 'Grant', 'first': 'Nieves'}
{'last': 'Mendoza', 'first': 'Sheryl'}
{'last': 'Hardy', 'first': 'Clayton'}
{'last': 'Wong', 'first': 'Deana'}
{'last': 'Parks', 'first': 'Stafford'}
{'last': 'Horton', 'first': 'Melissa'}
{'last': 'Johnston', 'first': 'Nanette'}
{'last': 'Sykes', 'first': 'Sherrie'}
{'last': 'Mckenzie', 'first': 'Monique'}
{'last': 'Coleman', 'first': 'Mccarty'}
{'last': 'Winters', 'first': 'Kelley'}
{'last': 'Barber', 'first': 'Lillie'}
{'last': 'Wright', 'first': 'Knight'}
{'last': 'Fox', 'first': 'Pratt'}
{'last': 'Stewart', 'first': 'Richmond'}
{'last': 'Rose', 'first': 'Erica'}
```

---

**BTW:**

Page [CurlConverter.com](https://curlconverter.com/) can convert `curl` command to code in many languages - even Python.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in Javascript:

// API KEY
const API_KEY ="vza4lbzrzy3cyhg4nbzyjhmqzjlqr2p3qibd9986"

// Object for various requests
const request = {
fetchUsers: `https://api.json-generator.com/templates/-xdNcNKYtTFG/data?access_token=${API_KEY}`,
};

// Exporting request object. Making it available.
export default request;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).